# How to add previous commit as the new HEAD in current branch

Tags: git

Right now, I Have my project as

```
A-B-C-D-E-F
```

I would like to take C, do some quick changes, and push it so it would look like
A-B-C-D-E-F-C-C2
Eventually, I would like to go back to F and make that the head (so I dont want to delete this commit) so it will look like

```
A-B-C-D-E-F-C-C2-F-F2
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: What are C2 and F2?

Comment: Changes I make to the previous commits

Comment: What you are asking for doesn't really make sense. Git commits are not changesets; they are snapshots of the entire repository. Making C the head just means you have discarded whatever changes D, E, and F introduce. Restoring F would mean restoring D, E, F and discarding C2. What you probably want is something like: make a new branch starting at C; make changes and commit as C2; merge your new branch into master or rebase it on top of master, then continue.

Comment: If you want to have A-B-C-D-E-F-C then D-E-F are basically useless (because their content/changes are no longer present). What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Okay, so essentially I should clone new branch, reset to C, make changes to C2. Then merge that branch into my original?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `A-B-C-D-E-F` is `master`,

1. `git checkout -b mybranch C`
2. edit edit edit
3. `git commit ...` (to make C2)
4. `git checkout master`
5. `git merge mybranch`

This will give you something like

```
  G  master, my branch
  | \
  F  |
  |  |
  E  |
  |  |
  D  C2
  | /
  C
  |
  B
  |
  A
```

where `G` is the merge commit with `F` and `C2` as its parents.

If you would rather have `A-B-C-D-E-F-C2`, then you can replace step 4 and 5 with `git rebase master`. You can then perform a fast-forward merge of `mybranch` into `master` to avoid the separate merge commit.